# Query entity by class name

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

Doing full class name query with `Objectify` to get an Entity, is it possible? Like when I want to query for `class com.mypackage.MyClass` get the Entity and do further query on its fields.

**EDIT:**

For example:

```
daot.ofy().query(Class.forName("com.mypackage.MyClass"));
```

Will this work?

Comment: I'm afraid I really don't understand the question.  Can you state it a little more clearly?  Is it that you want to go from a classname in javascript to a query?  If so, look at Class.forName() to get the class object.

Comment: Right Class.forName will do, but the problem is how to do the actual query via ofy(), for all registered classes I can simple do daot.ofy().query(getClassFromString("com.mypackage.MyClass"))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your rephrased question is:  **Yes**